# Dictionary in python for different desktop and its cards

Tags: python, dictionary

Let us say there are various desktop data [hard coded into dictionary] which support specific controllers on it on different ports

```
ABC: Card1 in port1, card2 in port 2, card3 in port 3, card4 in port 4
DEF: card3 in port 2, card4 in port 3
GHI: card 4 in port 1, card 3 in port 2, card 2 in port 3, card 1 in port 1
```

How can a dictionary be constructed such that I can maintain above data ?

Later, so that I can read the dictionary and compare the desktop, card and port with the Desktop I have ?

Comment: its better to post any code that you already tried.http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
x = {
    'ABC': {
        'card1': 'port1',
        'card2': 'port2',
        'card3': 'port3',
        'card4': 'port4',
    },
    'DEF': {
        'card3': 'port2',
        'card4': 'port3',
    },
    'GHI': {
        'card4': 'port1',
        'card3': 'port2',
        'card2': 'port3',
        'card1': 'port1',
    },
}
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
x == y
=> True
y['ABC']['card3'] = 'port9'
x == y
=> False
```

Comment: Yes ! What would be the best way to maintain the above data in a python dictionary ?
Check dictionary for ABC ->Card3 should be in port 3
check my desktop ABC -> card 3 gives result port 3 hence, card 3 in in right port.
I would like to know what would be the best way to maintain desktop, card and port data in dictionary?